# how apply two differents styles to different nav components in bootstrap/uikit using less

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less

I'm using uikit/less which is pretty similar to bootstrap, my code includes two different navs which must have different styles, I know how change the global style changing the navbar.less variables but I'm not sure which is the right way for customize a nav avoiding a global change, I'd like something like this

```
#navA{
 @navbar-color:                                  @main-color;
}

#navB{
 @navbar-color:                                 @comp-color;
}
```

thanks!...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Recommendation**

I would advise creating a new custom class for each respective navigation with the appropriate background colors (which will then override what is in the framework). And regarding the variables, just create new ones custom to your site.

Example:

```
@blue: #1F39FF;
@red: #C5002F;

.blue-nav {
  background: @blue;
}

.red-nav {
  background: @red;
}
```

Don't try to change the framework directly since that can create unnecessary complications in the future (i.e., updates or migrating to a new framework).

Hope this helps!